# Calling a Clojure function with string inside swap?

Tags: macros, clojure

The macro, `transform!`, as defined below seems to work for `=> (transform! ["foo" 1 2 3])`. The purpose is to take in a list, with the first element being a string that represents a function in the namespace. Then wrapping everything into `swap!`.

The problem is that `transform!` doesn't work for `=> (transform! coll)`, where `(def coll ["foo" 1 2 3])`. I am getting this mystery exception:

```
#<UnsupportedOperationException java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nth not supported on this type: Symbol>
```

The function:

```
(defmacro transform! 
" Takes string input and update data with corresponding command function.
"  
  [[f & args]]  ;; note double brackets
 `(swap! *image* ~(ns-resolve *ns* (symbol f)) ~@args))
```

I find it strange that it works for one case and not the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros work at compile-time and operate on code, not on runtime data. In the case of `(transform! coll)`, the macro is being passed a single, unevaluated argument: the symbol `coll`.

You don't actually need a macro; a regular function will suffice:

```
(defn transform! [[f & args]]
  (apply swap! *image* (resolve (symbol f)) args)))
```

Resolving vars at runtime could be considered a code smell, so think about whether you really need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a symbol to the macro, namely coll. It will try to pull that symbol apart according to the destructuring statement [f & args], which won't be possible of course.

You can also use ([resolve](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/resolve) symbol) instead of (ns-resolve *ns* symbol).